# Issues with seperate css file for Instagram's in-app browser

Tags: html, css, web, instagram

In order to get around Instagram's in-app browser weird css errors, I used a script to dynamically load a separate css file upon detection of Instagram's in-app browser that would style the page correctly. The styling works for mostly all elements, except for 5 and I can't understand why.

I have tried moving the script around, using different styling, messing with html files, but it seems as if nothing can be applied to these specific elements. They will not change no matter what I put in the css file.

Below is part the part of my css file that is not rendering:

```
.wrapper-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28%;
}
#resume-tag {
    height: 12%;
}

#resume {
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 55%;
}

#swl {
    display: none;
}

#sws {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

Here is the related HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper-3">
        <img src="assets/images/Selected-Work-LG.svg" width="40%" id="swl" alt="Selected Work Large">
        <img src="assets/images/Selected-Work-S.svg" width = "45%" id="sws" alt="Selected Work Small">
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-3" id="resume-tag">
        <img src="assets/images/Resume.svg" width="26%" id="resume" alt="Resume">
    </div>
```

Here is some css from the file that works:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 68%;
}

#large-logo {
    display: none;
}

#small-logo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 255px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the script I am using in my html files:

```
    <script>
        console.log(navigator.userAgent); // Print the user agent to the console
        var isInstagram = /instagram/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        if (isInstagram) {
          var link = document.createElement('link');
          link.rel = 'stylesheet';
          link.href = 'instagram.css';
          document.head.appendChild(link);
        }
    </script>
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe those values get overwritten by more specific rules from your "regular" stylesheet?